# How can I make this MYSQL query with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables that will be used: News and Tags

The news table has a music_id field related to a music table and the tags table has the same aswell as a tag_id column. It holds multiple tag entries for each artist.

Tags looks like this

```
music_id | tag_id | user_id
    3        2         7
    3        3         12
    9        17        52
```

So each user can tag an artist with multiple tags that are different from each other.

I want to take the music_id from each of the news posts (news.music_id) and find the top tag for each artist on every row.

So it would be like

```
music_id | top_tag
  22         6
  15         4
  13         9
  22         6
  15         4
```

After that I want to order the tags by the most popular.

So I'm left with a result like

```
count | top_tag
  2        6
  2        4
  1        9
```

Hope this makes sense. I'm really stuck!

Comment: where is table tags and the third table ?

Comment: You say you want to find the top_tag for each artist on every row.  How are you going to determine which is the top tag?  You also say you want to order the top_tags by popularity.  How are you defining popularity?  Can you please clarify these areas?

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm having trouble explaining it. There are multiple tags for each artist inside of the tags table. A short example is in my first code snippet.

Each artists can be tagged with an unlimited amount of different tags, aswell as multiples of the same tag.

What I want to do is take the music.id FROM the news table and find the most popular tag for that music.id. So the most popular tag would be the tag that has the most entries next to the music_id.

So then for each post in the news table there is also a column that contains the most popular tag for the artist.

Comment: Can you please base your samples on **the same** test data set?

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting the question as "Order the tags by the number of music ids where they are the most popular tag on the music id".  The following query uses a subquery to calculate the counts by tag on the each `music_id`.  It also finds the maximum count for each `music_id' for the final aggregation:

```
select mt.tag_id, count(*) as musiccnt
from (select music_id, tag_id, count(*) as cnt
      from tags t
      group by music_id
     ) mt join
     (select music_id, max(cnt) as maxcnt
      from (select music_id, tag_id, count(*) as cnt
            from tags t
            group by music_id
           ) mt
      group by music_id
     ) m
     on mt.music_id = m.music_id and mt.cnt = m.maxcnt
group by mt.tag_id
order by musiccnt desc
```